# Problem with Pinecone in Firebase Functions

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, pinecone

I install Pinecone in angular project in firebase functions with npm uninstall @pinecone-database/pinecone.

Previously it worked well, but after introducing version 1 of pinecone, I cannot deploy functions.
I receive over 1000 bugs:
Errors  Files
51  node_modules/.pnpm/typescript@4.9.3/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:25
1002  node_modules/@types/web/index.d.ts:7

They disappear when I uninstall pinecone again, this is how I know that the problem is related to pinecone.

Exapmple of bugs are:
node_modules/@types/web/index.d.ts:18116:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'XPathResult'

node_modules/.pnpm/typescript@4.9.3/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17276:14
17276     readonly FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE: number;

node_modules/@types/web/index.d.ts:18111:14 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.

node_modules/@types/web/index.d.ts:17593:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.

I reinstalled pinecone several times and nothing worked. I also searched for answer on pinecone forum, but the problem didn't appear.  I created totally new angular project, copied sources files and tried to launch functions from scratch, but it didn't help either.

Comment: When I downdgraded pinecone client to version 0.1.6 it started to work again. So the problem is with this newest version in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Happened with yesterday's 1.0 update for typescript. It is being looked at here: https://github.com/pinecone-io/pinecone-ts-client/issues/102

Comment: @MarcinŻmigrodzki You would need to revert to the previous latest (we are currently using v0.1.6) and adjust your code accordingly until a fix is deployed.